# Query: How to run application without Visual Studio 2017 installed in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2017

System : Windows 10 x64
IDE : Visual studio 2017

If we have not installed visual studio 2017 in system and if we want to run the application c++ .exe which build on visual studio 2017 what should we need to do or which dll required to install in system?

-> is msvcp140d.dll, ucrtbased.dll, vcruntime140d.dll dll part of Redistributable files?
-> What's condition for licensing about msvcp140d.dll, ucrtbased.dll, vcruntime140d.dll ? if want to release c++ tool with .exe?

Comment: You aren't allowed to redistribute the debug runtimes, use a release build instead and install the redist package

Answer (score 0):

You could download vc_redist.xXX.exe from [Microsoft Downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) on the client cpmputer. Also, you could find it in your VS file, such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012`.